# Making network calls inside of dispatch_async does not seem to work?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, flurry, flurry-analytics

Is there anything wrong with making network calls inside of `dispatch_async`?

The code below doesn't log anything to Flurry when placed inside of `dispatch_async` but works when placed outside the function.

There's nothing in the Flurry documentation suggesting `dispatch_async` would cause issues.

Could someone kindly explain what is wrong with the code below?

```
func logFlurry(eventName: String, var userData: NSMutableDictionary?) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if (userData == nil) {
            userData = NSMutableDictionary()
        }
        userData!.setObject(USER.getUsername(), forKey: "Username")
        Flurry.logEvent(eventName, withParameters: userData! as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they suggest to do so on the main queue?

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev Aren't you supposed to do things like this on main queue? What's best practice?

Comment: Network calls generally are put on a background thread, because (and especially if you are making a network request that would have a huge response) otherwise the network call will block the UI (which runs on the main thread)

Comment: And to clarify, you are sure that the network call isn't working because you can check your Flurry dashboard and see that nothing is logged?  Then when you take your network call out of the `dispatch_async`, it's all good?

Or how are you verifying that it doesn't work?

Comment: @AO hi alexander could you post as an answer? then we can credit you as this was the right choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network calls generally are put on a background thread, because *(and especially if you are making a network request that would have a huge response)* otherwise the network call will block the UI (which runs on the main thread)

Comment: HI do you happen to know the answer to this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845670/uicollectionview-how-to-use-storyboard-to-create-custom-sections

Answer (score 1):

Try setting data of userData of passes dictionary outside of the block,

```
if (userData == nil) {
    userData = NSMutableDictionary()
}

userData!.setObject(USER.getUsername(), forKey: "Username")

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    Flurry.logEvent(eventName, withParameters: userData! as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}
```

Comment: OK will try but why does that matter?